# Need to make a relationship between the three models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

We have a user who can learn in several ways. In each direction, the user has some level. There are three models: **user, direction, level**. They need to be linked in such a way that the user can get a list of its directions, and in each direction its level. For example, `$user->directions[0]->level`.

Once again regarding the relationship. A user may have many directions, and a direction many users (many to many). Direction can have many levels, but the level is only one direction (one to many).

I use **Laravel 5.8**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a **User** has many **Directions** and a **Direction** has many **Users** you should use `belongsToMany` (Eloquent relationship which related to **many-to-many** relationship of database.) relationship.

And a **Direction** has many **Levels** but a **Level** has only one **Direction** you should use `hasMany` and `belongsTo` on **Direction** and **Level** respectively.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function directions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Direction::class);
    }
}
```

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Direction extends Model
{
    public function levels()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Level::class);
    }

    public funciton users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Level extends Model
{
    public function direction()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Direction::class);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In case you haven't defined database tables. This is how you may do it.

You can use Laravel migrations to create database tables.

**User Table**

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increment('id')->primary();
            // all the other columns goes here.
});
```

**Directions Table**

```php
Schema::create('directions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increment('id')->primary();
            // all the other columns goes here.
});
```

**Directions Users Table**

```php
Schema::create('direction_user_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unSignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->unSignedInteger('direction_id');
            // all the other columns goes here.
});
```

**Levels Table**

```php
Schema::create('levels', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increment('id')->primary();
            $table->unSignedInteger('direction_id');
            // all the other columns goes here.
});
```

Comment: Ok, but how will the orm understand exactly which level belongs to the user? I think there should be some kind of intermediate table that will link the user, the direction and level in it. Otherwise, how do you know that user A has a B level C in direction A, and a level E in D direction?

Comment: Before answer your questions, I may ask a quick question. Did you define the database tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can use relationships like below in laravel model.

For User model

```
public function directions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Direction','user_id');
}
```

For Direction model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User','id','user_id');
}

public function levels()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Level','direction_id');
}
```

For Level model

```
public function direction()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Direction','id','direction_id');
}
```